# Java String split with &#160; as pameter

Tags: java, string

I read a html file `parser. Jsoup.parse(new File("2005-08.html"),   "ISO-8859-1");` and then I need to split a string like `"+24&#160;-2"` into two: `"+24"` and `"-2"`. Then I pass this string to `System.out.println()` it prints as whitespase. I tried

```
s.split(" ");
s.split("&#160;");
```

but nothing works. I get one string `"+24 -2"`.

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\s+")));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch not helps

Comment: I think you just have a typo? Should be `s.split("&#160;")`, not `s.split("#160;")`. I just ran `"+24&#160;-2".split("&#160;")` in a Scala REPL and it evaluates to `Array(+24, -2)`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin both variants not work

Comment: String is immutable: `split` will not change it but return a new Array of Strings, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "**does not work**"? What is the output you are getting? Or does it even crash? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: what do you mean by "not work"? What's your result?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could it be that you print `s`? Note that `String#split` does **not** change the `String` it was invoked on, instead it returns a new `String[]` result that can be saved inside a variable.

Comment: @Zabuza yes I print it.

Comment: @user3378876 It seems like your string `s` may have come from the output running an HTML parser on the string `"+24&#160;-2"`, rather than `s` actually *being* the string `"+24&#160;-2"`. Can you show us the code where `s` is defined?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Yes it is from html parser. Jsoup.parse(new File("2005-08.html"), "ISO-8859-1");

Comment: @Zabuza Andreas answered in comment for 1st answer but it is comment and I cannot mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say your input is `+24&#160;-2` and you want to split it into `+24` and `-2`.

Well that is pretty easy and it uses the same technique than your tried with:

```
String s = "+24&#160;-2";

// The correct delimiter begins with an '&'
String[] result = s.split("&#160;");

// Print the result
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

The output is `[+24, -2]`. You can access the results by `result[0]` which yields `+24` and `result[1]` which is `-2`.

---

If you like you can also parse them as `Integer` by using:

```
int firstValue = Integer.parseInt(result[0]);
int secondValue = Integer.parseInt(result[1]);
```

Comment: However, if the text does not actually contain the characters `&#160;`, but the text was processed by a web browser, which replaced the `&#160;` characters with a [No-Break Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) character, then it should be `split("\u00A0")`.

Comment: @Andreas that probably should be reworded and posted as answer, after the edit of the question